# PHP: Corrupted file in network?

Tags: php, windows, file, networking, internet-explorer-11

I need to read a file (always a image) to download it, but it always corrupted.

```
$path = 'S:\PATH\TO\ART2770.jpg';
$file = 'ART2770.jpg';
$filename = basename($file);
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

switch( $file_extension ) {
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
    default:
}

header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)) . ' GMT');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');  // Allow support for download resume
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));  // File size
header('Content-Encoding: none');
header('Content-Type: '.$ctype);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);  // Make the browser display the Save As dialog
readfile($path);
exit;
```

What i've tried:

1. It's **not** a `safe_mode` problem, because it's already off;
2. It's **not** a `BOM` problem, because I've checked it already;
3. It's **not** a `?>\n` or some kind of white space in the end of the code because I've checked it already;
4. EDIT: It's **not** a `\n<?` or some kind of white space in the `begin` of the code because I've checked it already;
5. I **can** display the image using the `img` html tag without any trouble;
6. I have all permissions in the target folder;
7. `S:/PATH/TO/ART2770.jpg`, `S:\\PATH\\TO\\ART2770.jpg` and `file:///S:/PATH/TO/ART2770.jpg` also fail to return a valid file.

I'm using **Windows 7 64 Bits**, **PHP Version 5.3.5**, **Xampp 1.7.4** and **Internet Explorer 11** (Must work on IE, no need to work on other browsers).

Comment: Is it normal that you have this :
header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); 
And that you are trying to display a JPEG?

Comment: Oops. Corrected. Still don't work.

Comment: Try with `$path = 'S:\\PATH\\TO\\ART2770.jpg';`

Comment: Thanks, but don't work either. Will add to my question

Comment: What is before your first line of code? Any spaces before the first <?php ?

Comment: @MdeLorimier Nope, I've checked it too. No BOM or empty spaces/special characters before the first `<?php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that the right way to input the network path is **\\PATH\TO\ART2770.jpg**, without even mention the network `S:` letter.

Comment: Well, that is because the S: is a map drive which is relative to your user. If the user running PHP does not have that map drive, that is why.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

`header('Content-Type: $ctype');`

will out put `Content-Type: $ctype`

Try `header("Content-Type: $ctype");` or `header('Content-Type: '.$ctype);`

Also: Make sure there is no whitespace before `<?php`

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I'm tired and not thinking very well. Used your suggestion, but still don't work...